# JQuery UI Tabs & Dragon Naturally Speaking software

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, accessibility, jquery-ui-tabs

Our software uses JQuery UI Tabs with the ajax options to load tab areas full of input fields. We have two employees that are handicapped and need to be able to use the Dragon Naturally Speaking software. The software works in the initial search screens, but once a tab set is loaded with dynamic form fields, the software does not recognize the fields to allow  them to be filled out. Anyone have the same issue? We use version 10 of the Dragon Software, I understand that there's an upgrade and I am wondering if that would fix our issues or if perhaps anything can be done in my code to assist the application.

===================================

So after some testing with the actual software, it works amazingly with Firefox, but not Internet Explorer. It will work on the first few form fields but when the tabs are loaded with new dynamic fields, it doesn't seem to recognize them in IE.

Answer (score 1):

One of the nuances of jQuery UI Tabs is the ajax load.  It caused a major issue in one of my apps, where the users wanted to be able to click back and forth between tabs without the ajax measures clobbering changes they made each time a tab is navigated away from.  The solution in that case was to load all content in the main document (making it always available to the DOM) and using the tabs simply to switch divs, not load content.  On a more involved page, one could just turn off Ajax Loading and get content upon load, which might make it more available to Dragon.  Without specific code to play with, it's tough to isolate an exact fix.

The other possibility is that Dragon might be looking for elements that were on the page at the time of load.  Obviously, ajax throws a wrench in that requirement, which is what necessitates things like .live() and .on() in jQuery.  Yes, reaching out to Dragon could be a start, though I wonder how much help they will be with such a limited topic--there's virtually no chatter about it on the web.  A more technical resource might be [Scott Gonzales, the team lead for jQuery UI](http://www.linkedin.com/in/scottgonzalez).  His team does extensive work on ARIA considerations for jQuery, and likely would have a great idea what the issue is and how it could be overcome.  Scott's UI team [has a wiki here](http://wiki.jqueryui.com/w/page/12137947/FrontPage) where you could similarly get some great insight....they are always very helpful and responsive.

Comment: i actually found this [link]https://github.com/fnagel/jQuery-Accessible-RIA/wiki/Tabs[/link] which may help with the navigation of the tabs. the application has to work the way that it does in order to ensure that the data is always freshly loaded, and the save functionality is fired correctly. i will look into .live() and .on() when i get my hands on the newest dragon software and can test it. i will post my results here so maybe it can help someone else in the future.